# AppleScript for successfully importing photos to Aperture

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript, photos

I am trying to make an apple script for importing a large collection of photos to Aperture  as Aperture often crashes in this situation. For this reason I would like to import each file separately moving it into the Library.My initial try works on one picture:

```
on run argv
set file_name to item 1 of argv


tell application "Aperture"
activate
    tell library 1
      if not (exists project "OldPictures") then
          set theProject to make new project with properties {name:"OldPictures"}
      else
          set theProject to project "OldPictures"
      end if
end tell
with timeout of 600 seconds
      import file_name by moving into theProject
end timeout
end tell

end run
```

But it crashes if I run it in the following way

```
find /Volumes/Pictures/ -iname "*.jpg" -exec  osascript /Users/mac/apperture.scpt  {} \;
```

Comment: I know what you mean. linking to https://discussions.apple.com/message/22584864

Comment: I would change your question title to "How Can I import files individually into Aperture with AppleScript" or something similar. It should be more specific such that people with a similar issue can find this easily.

Answer (score 0):

## Brute-Force Muscle Import

You may want to try this hardcore script. It will take AGES to finish, but it should work, because it does what you ask…it adds each file ONE BY ONE to a specified project and checks to make sure there aren't any duplicates by **name only**. I am about to test this script on 13262 pictures. It will probably run all night, but it will hopefully beat the built-in importer that keeps failing.

I recommend that you create a test project on your first run, just to ensure you aren't importing duplicates. Optionally, you can then move the images into the appropriate project in Aperture. I have already set this up. If you want to ignore this and import them directly into the original project, you can do this by changing the following line:

- `my importToApertureAsReference(itemAlias, projectDst)`

to

- `my importToApertureAsReference(itemAlias, projectName)`

OS X 10.9.4

Aperture 3.5.1

*Disclaimer: I just threw it together. There is room for improvement, like checks to ensure that the files in the list are all pictures. I did not do any checks like that. This could be done in the shell command or using System Events to get the type of each file as it passes through. Also, your computer will flip out when you run this. I would suggest you don't do anything else on your computer.*

## AppleScript - Import Missing Files to Project one-by-one"

### By comparing names of pictures to names of files

### Updated 01.08.2014

I significantly improved the speed of the script by make bourne script do most of the work. AppleScript gets bogged down when talking to programs, but it is relatively fast when iterating lists. I just used bourne script's `find` command combined with `basename` to make a new list of all of the files without their paths. AppleScript iterates this list and compares it to the list of names in your designated project. If it finds one that does not exist in the project `projectName`, *then* it joins the path to the filename and adds it to the project destination `projectDst` as a reference. If you want to copy the file to the library and not only as a reference, you would need to adjust the handler `importToApertureAsReference` or create a new one called `importToApertureAsCopying` or `importToApertureAsMoving`.

```
set inputPath to "Volumes:Kielbasa:Camera:1970 - Fotos" as string
set inputPathHFS to inputPath as alias
log "inputPathHFS: " & inputPathHFS
set projectName to "1970 - Fotos" -- Check this project for duplicates
set projectDst to "AppleScript Import" -- This is where any missing files will be added
set importedList to {}

set inputPathPX to text 1 through -2 of POSIX path of inputPathHFS
log "inputPathPX: " & inputPathPX
set countItemsCommand to "find " & quoted form of inputPathPX & " -type f -maxdepth 1 \\! -name '.*' | wc -l"
set getItemsCommand to "find " & quoted form of inputPathPX & " -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec sh -c 'basename \"{}\"' \\;"

set itemCount to (do shell script countItemsCommand) as integer
set itemList to paragraphs of (do shell script getItemsCommand) as list
set missingItemsList to {}

set namesInProjectList to my getAllNamesInProject(projectName) as list

-- Check whether your project contains an object/item (image/video) with the same name
repeat with itemStep from 1 to count of itemList
    set thisItem to item itemStep of itemList
    log "This Item: " & thisItem
    set itemSplit to my splitExtension(thisItem)
    set itemName to item 1 of my splitExtension(thisItem)
    set itemExt to item 2 of my splitExtension(thisItem)
    log "Item Name: " & itemName & ", Item Ext: " & itemExt
    log "Checking if project " & projectName & " contains " & itemName
    set foundImages to my findAll(namesInProjectList, itemName)
    if foundImages is {} then -- if empty, then there is no match so image should be added to Aperture
        set end of missingItemsList to contents of thisItem -- this makes a new list of all missing images with extensions (no path), to import into Aperture you need to join this item with its full path

        set picAlias to (inputPathHFS as string) & thisItem as alias
        log "Importing: " & picAlias
        my importToApertureAsReference(picAlias, projectDst)
    else
        repeat with foundIndex in foundImages
            my deleteItem(namesInProjectList, foundIndex)
            log "Found Index: " & foundIndex
            log "Removed from namesInProjectList: " & thisItem
        end repeat
    end if
end repeat


return missingItemsList

(*
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with itemStep from 1 to count of itemList
        set thisItem to item itemStep of itemList
        log "This Item: " & thisItem
        set itemSplit to my splitExtension(thisItem)
        set {itemName, itemExt} to {item 1 of itemSplit, item 2 of itemSplit}
        log "Item Name: " & itemName & ", Item Ext: " & itemExt
        log "Checking if project " & projectName & " contains " & itemName
        -- Compare Lists
        if namesInProjectList does not contain itemName then
            if otherList does not contain itemName then
                -- Generate Alias from filename by joining inputpath and filename
                set thisFileAlias to inputPath & ":" & thisItem as alias -- eg "Volumes:Kielbasa:Camera:1970 - Fotos000_0014.jpg"
                my importToApertureAsReference(thisFileAlias, projectDst)
                log "Imported: " & thisFileAlias
                set end of importedList to thisFileAlias
            end if
        end if

    end repeat
end tell
*)
return importedList

on importToApertureAsReference(picAlias, projectName)
    log "Importing: " & picAlias
    tell application "Aperture"
        tell library 1
            if not (exists project projectName) then
                set projectDst to make new project with properties {name:projectName}
            else
                set projectDst to project projectName
            end if
            import picAlias by referencing into projectDst
        end tell
    end tell
end importToApertureAsReference


on getAllNamesInProject(projectName)
    tell application "Aperture"
        tell library 1
            tell project projectName
                set nameList to name of image versions
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    return nameList
end getAllNamesInProject


on splitExtension(file_name)
    set dot to "."
    tell AppleScript
        set oT to text item delimiters
        set text item delimiters to dot
        if (count text items of file_name) > 1 then
            set out_name to (text items 1 through -2 of file_name) as string
            set ext to last text item of file_name
        else
            set out_name to file_name
            set ext to ""
        end if
        set text item delimiters to oT
        if ext is not "" then set ext to dot & ext
        return {out_name, ext}
    end tell
end splitExtension

on deleteItem(lst, idx)
    local lst, idx, len, ndx, l
    try
        if lst's class is not list then error "not a list." number -1704
        script k
            property l : lst
        end script
        set len to count of k's l
        set ndx to idx as integer
        if ndx is 0 then
            error "index 0 is out of range." number -1728
        else if ndx < 0 then
            set ndx to len + 1 + ndx
            if ndx < 1 then error "index " & idx & ¬
                " is out of range." number -1728
        else if ndx > len then
            error "index " & idx & " is out of range." number -1728
        end if
        if ndx is 1 then
            return rest of k's l
        else if ndx is len then
            return k's l's items 1 thru -2
        else
            return (k's l's items 1 thru (ndx - 1)) & ¬
                (k's l's items (ndx + 1) thru -1)
        end if
    on error eMsg number eNum
        error "Can't deleteItem: " & eMsg number eNum
    end try
end deleteItem

on findAll(lst, val)
    local lst, val, res
    try
        if lst's class is not list then error "not a list." number -1704
        if {val} is not in lst then return {}
        set res to {}
        script k
            property l : lst
        end script
        repeat with i from 1 to count of k's l
            if k's l's item i is val then set res's end to i
        end repeat
        return res
    on error eMsg number eNum
        error "Can't findAll: " & eMsg number eNum
    end try
end findAll
```

## Python - Import Missing Files to Project one-by-one (uses AppleScript)

AppleScript was choking on the load of 13262 pictures. The lists are too much for AppleScript when they get big, so I decided to write a Python script. With Python, I could subtract two sets (lists as sets) from one another get create a new list containing only the missing items. This removes the need for checking each item in a list again each item in another list. It speeds up the process significantly.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
# Imports
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import unicodedata
import codecs
import os


inputPath = "/Volumes/Kielbasa/Camera/1970 - Fotos" ## This is the source folder containing all images and videos you want to ensure are in your project (projectOriginal)
projectOriginal = "1970 - Fotos" ## This is where photos from original input are (if you just want to import everything from harddrive one by one, then create an empty project and use it here)
projectDst = "Python Import" ## This is where you will import all of the images and videos that are missing from you project. It is a debugging project (so that you don't screw anything up). You can then drag the images over to the projectOriginal project after ensuring that everything worked correctly.

importedList = []

getItemsCommand = """find '%s' -type f -maxdepth 1 ! -name '.*' -exec sh -c 'basename "{}"' \;""" % inputPath

#subprocess.check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
## itemsListEXT is a list of all files in your HD folder with extensions (Aperture projects import filenames without extensions, which I henceforth refer to as names). This list will be used to reconstruct the file paths later. It is important to have this if you have files with different extensions (e.g. images and movies, jpg, jpeg, png, raw)
itemsListEXT = subprocess.check_output(getItemsCommand, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash").splitlines()
itemCount = len(itemsListEXT)

def getItemsInProject(projectOriginal):
    cmd = """osascript<<END
    tell application "Aperture"
            tell library 1
                tell project "%s"
                    return name of image versions
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    END""" % projectOriginal
    itemsListEXT = subprocess.check_output(cmd,shell=True,executable="/bin/bash").split(', ')
    return itemsListEXT

## namesInProjectList is a list containing all names of images inside your projectOriginal project.
namesInProjectList = getItemsInProject(projectOriginal)

## namesOnHDList is a list that will be populated with all of the items in itemsListEXT, but without the extensions. The indexes must be the same between these two lists for reconstructing the file paths later.
namesOnHDList = []

for itemStep,thisItem in enumerate(itemsListEXT):
    #print itemStep, thisItem.decode('UTF-8')
    name,ext = os.path.splitext(thisItem)
    namesOnHDList.append(name)

missingItemsList = []
for itemStep,thisItem in enumerate(namesOnHDList):
    if thisItem in namesInProjectList:
        ## Just a place holder
        continue
    else:
        ## This reconstructs full paths out of all the missing item names by getting name + extension from itemsListEXT (the indexes in these two lists MUST be the same)
        missingItemsList.append(os.path.join(inputPath,itemsListEXT[itemStep]))

## This is for debugging only. You can compare the total number of missing items to the difference between your project and HD items. If that number is the same as the sum of items in missingItemsList, then it is likely working.
print len(missingItemsList)
print missingItemsList


def importToApertureAsReference(objectPath,projectDestination):
    scpt = '''
    on run {objectPath,projectDestination}
        set objectAlias to POSIX file objectPath as alias
        set projectName to projectDestination
        tell application "Aperture"
            tell library 1
                if not (exists project projectName) then
                    set projectDst to make new project with properties {name:projectName}
                else
                    set projectDst to project projectName
                end if
                import objectAlias by referencing into projectDst
            end tell
        end tell
    end run
    '''
    args = [objectPath, projectDestination]
    p = Popen(['osascript', '-'] + args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = p.communicate(scpt)
    print (p.returncode, stdout, stderr)
    print "--> Imported: " + objectPath +  " to Project: " +  projectDestination

## Add all items from the missingItemsList to your Aperture project destination (projectDst)
countItems = len(missingItemsList)
for itemStep,thisItem in enumerate(missingItemsList):
    importToApertureAsReference(thisItem,projectDst)
    print "Item: " + str(itemStep) + " of " + str(countItems)
```

---

## Originally-posted AppleScript

```
set inputPath to "Volumes:Kielbasa:Camera:1970 - Fotos" as alias
log "inputPath: " & inputPath
set projectName to "1970 - Fotos" -- Check this project for duplicates
set projectDst to "AppleScript Import" -- This is where any missing files will be added
set importedList to {}

set inputPathPX to text 1 through -2 of POSIX path of inputPath
log "inputPathPX: " & inputPathPX
set countItemsCommand to "find " & quoted form of inputPathPX & " -type f \\! -name '.*' | wc -l"
set getItemsCommand to "find " & quoted form of inputPathPX & " -type f ! -name '.*'"

set itemCount to (do shell script countItemsCommand) as integer
set itemList to paragraphs of (do shell script getItemsCommand) as list


set namesList to my getAllNamesInProject(projectName) as list
set otherList to my getAllNamesInProject("Test Project") as list


tell application "System Events"
    repeat with itemStep from 1 to count of itemList
        tell me to set itemAlias to POSIX file (item itemStep of itemList) as alias
        log itemAlias
        set itemName to name of itemAlias
        set fileNameNOEXT to item 1 of my splitExtension(itemName)
        log "Checking if project " & projectName & " contains " & fileNameNOEXT
        if namesList does not contain fileNameNOEXT then
            if otherList does not contain fileNameNOEXT then
                my importToApertureAsReference(itemAlias, projectDst)
                set end of importedList to itemAlias
            end if
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

return importedList

on importToApertureAsReference(picAlias, projectName)
    log "Importing: " & picAlias
    tell application "Aperture"
        tell library 1
            if not (exists project projectName) then
                set projectDst to make new project with properties {name:projectName}
            else
                set projectDst to project projectName
            end if
            import picAlias by referencing into projectDst
        end tell
    end tell
end importToApertureAsReference


on getAllNamesInProject(projectName)
    tell application "Aperture"
        tell library 1
            tell project projectName
                set nameList to name of image versions
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    return nameList
end getAllNamesInProject


on splitExtension(file_name)
    set dot to "."
    tell AppleScript
        set oT to text item delimiters
        set text item delimiters to dot
        if (count text items of file_name) > 1 then
            set out_name to (text items 1 through -2 of file_name) as string
            set ext to last text item of file_name
        else
            set out_name to file_name
            set ext to ""
        end if
        set text item delimiters to oT
        if ext is not "" then set ext to dot & ext
        return {out_name, ext}
    end tell
end splitExtension
```

Tip: You can watch what is happening if you click on the events or response option at the bottom of your AppleScript editor (better to do this before running the script)